# Divs' number fit to browser window with resizing

Tags: jquery, html, resize

Here is this code:
**https://jsfiddle.net/qw3fp7sk/**

The code displays same sized divs on the page, and the number of divs fits to the actual size of page, wihtout scrolling.

I want change number of divs on the page on the fly when I change the browser's window size. The divs' number must be fit to the window without scrolling.

Currently, the divs' number change after page's resizing only if I click jsfiddle's Run button.

Here is the codefragment, that is not working:

```
   $(window).on('resize', function() {

        // define global width and height variables
        var width = new jqUpdateSize().width;
        var height = new jqUpdateSize().height;

        // define div numbers to actual screen width (on one line)
        var lastw = '';
        for (var i = divwidthCalc; i < width; i+=divwidthCalc) {
        lastw++;
        }

        // define div numbers to actual screen height (on one row)
        var lasth = '';
        for (var i = divheightCalc; i < height; i+=divheightCalc) {
        lasth++;
        }

        // define the max div numbers
        var numDivMaxOnPage = lastw * lasth;

        //alert(numDivMaxOnPage);

        setGridDimensions(numDivMaxOnPage);


    });
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with your `numDivMaxOnPage` variable. It defines two times.

```
// divs w, h, margin
    // you can modify these datas
    var divborder = 5;
    var divwidth = 100;
    var divheight = 100;
    // calculating the values to define max div on lines and on rows
    var divwidthCalc = divwidth+(divborder*2);
    var divheightCalc = divheight+(divborder*2);

    var numDivMaxOnPage = null;


  function setGridDimensions(n) {
        var html ='';
        for (var i = 0; i < numDivMaxOnPage; i++) {
        html += '<div class="row">' + (i+1);
        html += '</div>';
        }
        $(document.body).html(html);

         // div size css
        $('.row').css({'width': divwidth + 'px', 'height' : divheight + 'px', 'border-width' : divborder + 'px'});
    };

    calculate();

    // not working function...
    $(window).on('resize', function() {

        calculate();


    });

  function calculate() {
        var width = $(window).width();
        var height = $(window).height();

        // define div numbers to actual screen width (on one line)
        var lastw = '';
        for (var i = divwidthCalc; i < width; i+=divwidthCalc) {
        lastw++;
        }

        // define div numbers to actual screen height (on one row)
        var lasth = '';
        for (var i = divheightCalc; i < height; i+=divheightCalc) {
        lasth++;
        }

        // define the max div numbers
        numDivMaxOnPage = lastw * lasth;

    // run function
        setGridDimensions(numDivMaxOnPage);

  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ne05rftp/1/

Comment: The original code works well without hidden overflow. The problem is, that the divs' number not change automatically, if I resize the browser's window (Moz or Chrome window). I want, if I change the browser's window size, the divs fill the whole page on the fly.

Comment: @earlmanster I have updated the solution see new [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ne05rftp/1/)